# EJS syntax error while compiling ejs code

Tags: ejs

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in C:\Users\hp\short.nner\views\index.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
    at new AsyncFunction (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:661:12)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:396:16)
    at handleCache (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:233:18)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\hp\short.nner\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\hp\short.nner\server.js:49:17
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
```

Here's my code:

```html
    <%=Url.forEach(shortUrl => { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<%= shortUrl.full %>">
                                <%= shortUrl.full %>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<%= shortUrl.short %>">localhost:3000/<%= shortUrl.short %></a
              >
            </td>
            <td><%= shortUrl.clicks %></td>
            <td><%= shortUrl.GivenEmail %>
          </tr>
          <% }) %>
```

I really don't know why I am getting this error please help.
I did give the Url as an option to my ejs but I get this strange error on running it.

Comment: sorry  i published wrong title by mistake

Comment: have edited it now

Comment: `<%=Url.forEach(shortUrl => { %>` looks incomplete.

Comment: i used this  const Url = await ShortUrl.find({ realEmail: email}); in my server.js . Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: if i remove '=' from 1st line I just see {} on my site.

Comment: It just seem incomplete. Have you use anything like that for other places in any other of your codes? Or is this the first time you use such method?

Comment: i use ejs sometimes i don't use it much

Comment: Try changing it to `<%=Url.forEach((shortUrl) => { %>`

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: Wait, I just saw your comment _"if I remove '=' from 1st line I just see {} on my site."_ . That means it works after that but there is no result from the `Url`? That's a different issue then, currently the error is coming from the first `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to fully test your code yesterday because I was on mobile.

The problem is actually coming from the `=` in the beginning of `<%=Url.forEach(shortUrl =>`. Just remove it like this should work:

```
 <% Url.forEach(shortUrl => { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<%= shortUrl.full %>">
                                <%= shortUrl.full %>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<%= shortUrl.short %>">localhost:3000/<%= shortUrl.short %></a
              >
            </td>
            <td><%= shortUrl.clicks %></td>
            <td><%= shortUrl.GivenEmail %>
          </tr>
          <% }) %>
```

That should dismiss the error.